# Expanded widgets must be placed inside Flex widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

New to flutter, can some one tells me whats wrong with below code[image]

```
  class GamePage extends StatelessWidget {
  int _row;
  int _column;

  GamePage(this._row,this._column);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      child:new Expanded(
          child:new GridView.count(crossAxisCount: _column,children: new List.generate(_row*_column, (index) {
        return new Center(
            child: new CellWidget()
        );
      }),) )


    );
  }
}
```

Attaching error screenshot.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You do not have a `Flex` ancestor.

> An Expanded widget must be a descendant of a Row, Column, or Flex, and the path from the Expanded widget to its enclosing Row, Column, or Flex must contain only StatelessWidgets or StatefulWidgets (not other kinds of widgets, like RenderObjectWidgets).

I am not sure about the need for `Expanded` in your case. But removing it or wrapping it in a `Column` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 69):

## Crash

This crashes because Expanded is not a descendant of a Flex widget:

```
Container(
  child: Expanded(
    child: MyWidget(),
  ),
)
```

## Acceptable

Here Expanded *is* a descendant of Flex:

```
Flex(
  direction: Axis.horizontal,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Row is also a Flex widget:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
  ],
)
```

And so is Column:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: MyWidget(),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Another option is to just get rid of the Expanded widget:

```
Container(
  child: MyWidget(),
)
```

Comment: What are some widgets that are Expanded widgets?  I don't see an Expanded below my `Flexible with flex:1` .  Flexible <- Padding <-Container with decoration BoxDecoration with DecorationImage with AssetImage that uses `fit: BoxFit.scaledown`.  I get errors locally but it displays fine in the browser and mobile but on firebase does not display.

Comment: I had a `SafeArea <- Expanded` took out the `Expanded` and errors went away.

Answer (score 4):

In my case issue was solved

```
 Flex(
        direction: Axis.vertical,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Text("Issue was solved"),
       )
     ])
```

Comment: If you have any questions or queries about it ask me...

Answer (score 1):

You need to try using `Flex` Widget on that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

sometimes it can also happen if you have an expended widget inside the SingleChildScrollView widget, then it shows the blank screen. If you have any expended widget inside SingleChildScrollView remove it and it will solve the problem.

**Before**

```
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(
     children: [
      Container(),
       Expanded(
       child: Container(),
        ),
       ],
      ),
      ),
```

**After**

```
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(
     children: [
      Container(),
      Container(),
       ],
      ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple example related to the error but with Expanded and ConstrainedBox :

The code:

```
Column(
  children:  [
    ConstrainedBox(
      child: Expanded(
        child: ...
      )
    )
  ]
```

The error message:

> [...] Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
> The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a ConstrainedBox widget.

Why the code is the code not working properly ?
In this example, Expanded must have the Column as direct Parent (which is a compatible parent type).

The solution:

```
Column(
  children:  [
   Expanded(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        child: ...
      )
    )
  ]
```